# How to reduce Initial loading time when using custom font files in angular 7?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have kept the local font file in the assets/fonts folder. Totally I used 3 types of fonts (lato,raleway,glyphicons-regular).

[image]

In my index.html under "head" tag, I write like below,

```
<link rel="preload" href="./assets/fonts/Lato/Lato-Semibold.woff2" as="font" crossorigin>
    <link rel="preload" href="./assets/fonts/Lato/Lato-Black.woff2" as="font" crossorigin>
    <link rel="preload" href="./assets/fonts/Lato/Lato-Bold.woff2" as="font" crossorigin>
    <link rel="preload" href="./assets/fonts/Lato/Lato-Heavy.woff2" as="font" crossorigin>
    <link rel="preload" href="./assets/fonts/Lato/Lato-Medium.woff2" as="font" crossorigin>
    <link rel="preload" href="./assets/fonts/Lato/Lato-Regular.woff2" as="font" crossorigin>

    <link rel="preload" href="./assets/fonts/Raleway/Raleway-Black.woff2" as="font" crossorigin>
    <link rel="preload" href="./assets/fonts/Raleway/Raleway-Bold.woff2" as="font" crossorigin>
    <link rel="preload" href="./assets/fonts/Raleway/Raleway-ExtraBold.woff2" as="font" crossorigin>
    <link rel="preload" href="./assets/fonts/Raleway/Raleway-Medium.woff2" as="font" crossorigin>
    <link rel="preload" href="./assets/fonts/Raleway/Raleway-MediumItalic.woff2" as="font" crossorigin>
    <link rel="preload" href="./assets/fonts/Raleway/Raleway-Regular.woff2" as="font" crossorigin>
    <link rel="preload" href="./assets/fonts/Raleway/Raleway-SemiBold.woff2" as="font" crossorigin>

    <link rel="preload" href="./assets/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf" as="font" crossorigin>
```

And created a file called fonts.scss and import all the fonts like below,

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Lato-Medium";
  src: url("/assets/fonts/Lato/Lato-Medium.woff2") format('woff2');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Lato-Regular";
  src: url("/assets/fonts/Lato/Lato-Regular.woff2") format('woff2');
}
```

I am using gzip compression and implemented PWA.
After take "ng build --prod" build and deploy the app and check the performance in "chrome lighthouse", the report shows, the preload key requests takes lots of time. How to reduce this time? any solution?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since you already include font in your scss file like this

```
src: url("/assets/fonts/Lato/Lato-Medium.woff2") format('woff2');
```

So you can simply add the font you need to your scss file and remove it out from your index.html

Also add your font to ngsw-config.json to cache it

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/favicon.ico",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js",
        ],
        "urls": [
          "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" // add your font here
        ]
      }
    }, {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/images/**",
          "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```